# Boolean expression in Ruby - difference betwen or and ||

Tags: ruby, boolean

Could someone please explain to me the differences of this two following lines of code?

```
puts false or true or false or false or false
```

I don't understand why the result of the execution of that line suppose to be different of:

```
puts false || true || false || false || false
```

I would be grateful if someone could explain that to me.

Comment: How many answers you want? Go here http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby%5D+%22%7C%7C%22+%22or%22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p false or true #=> false => same as  (p false) or true
p false || true #=> true  => same as  p (false or true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby have inherited some of its control flow from Perl. So in Ruby `and` and `or` are for control flow, and `&&` and `||` are boolean operators. This also means that `and` and `or` have higher precedence than `&&` and `||`

Ex:

`and` is used like:

```
 (true) and puts `true`
```

which is equivalent to

```
if true then
  puts "true"
end
```

and `&&` should by used like:

```
true && false
```

which is `false`.